# How to check if column in Teradata is CASESPECIFIC or NOT CASESPECIFIC

Tags: teradata

Let say I have a Teradata table like:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
  id int, 
  nc CHAR(20) NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  nv VARCHAR(20) NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  c CHAR(20) CASESPECIFIC)
```

How can I check which column is `CASESPECIFIC` and which is `NOT CASESPECIFIC` using `JDBC` or regular SQL query to Teradata?

So far I tested the below and it seems they do not provide such information:

- [DatabaseMetaData#getColumns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
- [ResultSetMetaData.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)
- `help column c from test.x`

Are there any options to check?

### EDIT

As @Fred mentioned:

> HELP COLUMN returns the same "Uppercase" flag values as dbc.ColumnsV.
>   And for Teradata JDBC, the ResultSetMetadata interface
>   (resultset.getMetaData) has the method isCaseSensitive(columnPosition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used it before, but take a look at the `UpperCaseFlag` field in `dbc.columns`.  From the Teradata (Data Dictionary) manual:

> **Possible Values for UpperCaseFlag**
>
> U - Uppercase, not specific
> C - Not uppercase, specific
> N - Not uppercase, not specific
> B - Both
>
> *Note: Case flags U, C, and B are valid only for CHAR, VARCHAR, and LONG VARCHAR columns.*

You can test using this query:

```
SELECT 
  col.*,
  CASE WHEN col.UpperCaseFlag = 'C' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS CaseSpecificFlag
FROM dbc.columnsV col
INNER JOIN dbc.tablesV t ON col.DatabaseName = t.DatabaseName 
  AND col.TableName = t.TableName AND t.tableKind = 'T' -- Only get tables
WHERE col.TableName = 'x'
AND col.DatabaseName = <database_name> -- Specify database name (if needed)
;
```

I'm not 100% sure about the 'B' option.  Test it out and see how it works.

Comment: Keep in mind, for views this column is (at least in my system) always null.

Comment: Dang it, hit enter too soon.  You can join this back to TablesV and exclude rows where tablesv.tablekind <> 'T'.

Comment: Oh good point.  I updated the query to include a join to `dbc.tables`.  Thanks Andrew :)

Comment: This answer is correct, but the question is misleading. HELP COLUMN returns the same "Uppercase" flag values as dbc.ColumnsV. And for Teradata JDBC, the ResultSetMetadata interface (resultset.getMetaData) has the method isCaseSensitive(columnPosition). It is true that this info is not available via DatabaseMetaData.getColumns.

Comment: @Fred Thank you. I don't know why I missed that in the first place. I haven't done my homework properly... ; /